# I have a data set that has a column with hundreds of dates listed out like "August 21, 2020" and so on.I want to extract only the month (SQL)

Tags: sql, date

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gYE5V.png)

Here is a snapshot of some of the data I am trying to extract only the month and place this into a new table. This is in SQL.

Comment: Please tag your DBMS. What have you tried so far?

Comment: A snapshot of data should be given as TEXT, not as an IMAGE

Comment: Column data type?

Comment: For advice on how to improve your question see [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uZBo0.png)

Answer (score 1):

```
select month(convert(date,<table_date>,101))
```

Comment: ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''August 21, 2020',101))'

Comment: Please when OP did not specify which DBMS is used, you should only give STANDARD-SQL answers, and this one is not standard. (But MS-SQL specific)